# How do you access query params in a Django Rest Framework 3.0 serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework 2.x you could access, for example, the "fields" query parameter in a serializer like this:

```
   fields = self.context['request'].QUERY_PARAMS.get('fields')
```

That no longer works in DRF 3.0, but I can't find the change documented in the API except in general terms. It looks like it might be something like `self.context.get('request')?????` but I can't figure it out.

How would you do it in DRF 3.0? I'm talking about accessing the query.params in the *serializer* rather than in the view.

thanks

John

Answer (score 34, accepted):

this is it for DRF 3:

```
fields = self.context.get('request').query_params.get('fields')
```